# How to Integrate Sharepoint with Reporting Services in Native Mode?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sharepoint, ssrs

I'm trying to do [something like this](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-12-SharePoint_and_SQL_Server_Reporting_Services_-_Installation_and_Setup.aspx) but with native mode (less integration).
All of the directions I can find tell you how to set up Sharepoint integrated mode but I need to find out what the steps are for setting up native mode?

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you are running SSRS in native mode, the most integration you can get with SharePoint is to use the Reporting Services Web Parts for viewing reports from your SQL Server. Take a look at this blog post for setup details:

http://mindsharpblogs.com/kathy/archive/2008/02/01/4247.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that got me start though the install now isn't working.  Follow up question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/123134/sharepoint-and-ssrs-native-integration-not-seeing-web-parts-after-cabinet-file