# Sharepoint and SSRS Native Integration - Not seeing web parts after cabinet file install

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssrs

I followed the [steps here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159772.aspx) to set up Sharepoint integration with reporting services (SSRS) using native mode. (i.e., get a report explorer and viewer web parts)

However after adding the cabinet file e.g.,

```
STSADM.EXE -o addwppack -filename "C:\ Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Reporting Services\SharePoint\RSWebParts.cab" -globalinstall
```

I still don't see report explorer in the web parts list.  Do you guys have any ideas?  I'm very stuck and confused :-(  Let me know if additional information would be helpful.

**Update**

There was an error message, any idea what it means?

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
C:\temp\RSWebParts.cab: The Web Part deployment failed.
```

Why I didn't see it before (if you care, probably not relevant):

*I'm on windows server 2008 and I was getting the access denied error, so I changed stsadm.exe to run as administrator in properties.  This caused it to run in a new window which immediately closed so I never saw any output and assumed it succeeded.  I switch to calling the stsadm command from a batch file and only ran the batch file as administrator and now I can see the output.*

I also noticed this in the event log:

```
SQL Database 'moss_Central_Admin_Content' on SQL Server instance 's1' not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

Cannot open database "moss_Central_Admin_Content" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'dom\greg'.
```

**Update 2**

I made myself dbo of that database and reran.  STSADM said it was successful but I still don't see options for the new web parts.

Here's what I get with this command:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN>stsadm.exe -o enumwppacks

rswebparts.cab, http://serv/
rswebparts.cab, http://serv:8020/
rswebparts.cab, http://serv:8010/
```

I'm not sure it matters but when I use Sharepoint on the web, it uses port 8000.

Comment: Did you set up reporting services in the sharepoint mode?

Comment: Do you mean setting up the reporting services database in sharepoint integrated mode?  Supposedly I don't have to do that using this approach.

Comment: @Greg_the_Ant was there any output from the stsadm command? Only thing I can think of right now is you are on Windows 2008 and didn't run your command prompt as an admin - but that should give you an "access denied" error.

Comment: @Greg_the_Ant also - just remembered you should be able to do a "stsadm -o enumwppacks" and it will give you a list of any deployed web part packages. RsWebParts.cab should show up in this list.

Comment: @MattB, there was an error (see updated question).  I'm going to try becoming dbo of moss_Central_Admin_Content.  I'll report back later.

Comment: @Greg_the_Ant - your other option would be to login to the SharePoint server as the account that installed SharePoint, that should have sufficient permissions in the db.

Comment: @MattB et al, I updated the question with my latest progress.  Any thoughts?  Do I maybe need to restart the server?  Restart IIS?

Comment: @Greg_the_Ant - addwppack without a URL parameter should deploy the package to all your web applications except Central Admin. If you look at the list of web applications in Central Admin, what are each of the ones listed in enumwppacks? And does the http://serv:8000/ site show up?

Comment: @MattB I think you're right.  I didn't install to central admin.  However when I go to the main site, I don't have the option to create a web part page.  When I click on site actions there's only a "create page" option.  Any ideas on that?

Comment: Update: I can still go directly to the create url: http://[server name]/_layouts/create.aspx  and I do see the new web parts options.  Everything is working!  Thanks for all the help!  @MattB, if you want to write an answer that says "see my comments" I could mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the original question was that on Windows 2008 (due to UAC) you need to run STSADM from an administrative command prompt.

See the comments on the question and Greg_the_Ant's updates for further discussion.